# Insert Into from another Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert into a table in a different database from the source data. Here's an example of the query I've got so far:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT
        Col1_old AS Expr0, Col2_old AS Expr1, Col3_old AS Expr2
    FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable
```

The problem I'm facing is that none of the column names from the source database are recognized.

Comment: That looks correct.  Highlight and run the SELECT statement alone  if it doesn't run check the spelling.  OR, in the object explorer, right click the table and "Select Top 1000 Rows"  that will generate the query with the correct 3 part name and you can copy it with the correct column names.

Comment: Agreed.  Your syntax is fine.  You can also see the columns names if you run `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable;`.  That's about all we can help you with; there's no way for us to know what the correct column names are without seeing the schema.

Comment: Add some DDL to define the structure.  Maybe use dbfiddle.uk

Comment: What exactly does "none ... are recognized" mean? I see `Col1_old AS Expr0` and suspect you are having issues with some sort of IDE / query builder.

Comment: Aside... the `as name` constructs in your select statement are redundant - the column names are specified in the insert's column list and that's the order they're expected to be in.